# Using Drupal for SaaS - New database per user?

Tags: 7

I want to configure my D7 site so new users get their own database, so when they log content, create organic groups, etc, this data is just for them - and does not show on other user's accounts.

In a way this is a multisite, but I do not need to have each user have user.example.com, unless that is the solution to the problem.

If anyone has done this before, I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at existing services like Drupal Gardens and Buzzr? I don't know if there is any documentation about how exactly they do it, but make sure to check it out.